# Generating deterministic keypair using SubtleCrypto interface of the Web Crypto API

Tags: javascript, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric, deterministic, webcrypto-api

I was wondering if there is a way to generate deterministic asymmetric keypair using some kind of input (password or email), using **SubtleCrypto** interface of the **WebCrypto API**.

I managed to do this using [Cryptico](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico) library, but I would like to know is there a more native way to do this, using built in API?

Comment: Is there something in the [documentation of SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey) that you're not understanding?

Comment: Yes. How to generate deterministic keypair. (Always the same keypair based on some user input)

Comment: So... you've tried the various methods and found that they didn't? That would be helpful information to have in your question....

Comment: Yes, I tried. But with no success. And according to the documentation, there is no option to do that. There is option to create deterministic symmetric key, using deriveKey function, but nothing to asymmetric keypair.